# Trying to get image to switch between two different source files when clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm a rank novice when it comes to JS.

I'm trying to write some javascript such that when I click on an image, it will switch to another image. Then, when I click it again, I want the image to switch back to the original image, and so on and so forth. Here's the simple Javascript function that I wrote in hopes of accomplishing this.

```
function diffImage(item) 
{
if(document.getElementById(item).src == "blank.jpg")
    {
        document.getElementById(item).src = "black.jpg";
    }
else
    {
        document.getElementById(item).src = "blank.jpg";
    }

}
```

And here is the tag for the image in question:

```
<img src="black.jpg" id="image1" onclick=diffImage("image1")>
```

Sadly, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: onclick='diffImage("image1");'

Comment: @dragon66 you need to use two different kinds of quotes, but otherwise correct (`onclick="diffimage('image1')"`)

Comment: You can actually use onclick="diffImage(this);" to get rid of all the document.getElementById() stuff.

Comment: your script doesn't work because you are only using one image. please see my answer.

Comment: @RayCheng no, the script does not work because onclick takes either a function or a string but not a function and it's parameter

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I've tried messing around with quotes within the img tag but it just makes the image totally static (I can get the img to change once under my existing code). @snies, if I understand your last comment correctly, I need to get rid of the parameter within the diffimage function and find a way for diffimage to work without a parameter. Am I reading that right? Like I said, I'm a pure novice, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my last comment is formulated in a bad way. The point is you should pass just one string as an argument, the whole argument should be in quotes. If you need to use a string as an argument to your function you should use different quotes. dragon66 provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

besides the quote problems mentioned in the comments by dragon66 and snies, your `if` condition statement may not do what you wanted because calling `element.src` in javascript returns the full URL, not just the image name. so you need to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the image name like below.

```
function diffImage(me){
    if(me.src.split("/").pop() === "blank.jpg"){
        me.src = "black.jpg";
    }
    else {
        me.src = "blank.jpg";
    }
}
```

and your HTML becomes...

```
<img src="black.jpg" id="image1" onclick="diffImage(this);">
```

Comment: me.getAttribute('src') would be another alternative, as it grabs the unparsed src.

Comment: @SeanJohnson, I'm sure you meant `me.getAttribute('src')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/soparrissays/7PxFH/

Answer (score 0):

```
function diffImage(img) 
{
    if(img.src.match(/blank/)) img.src = "black.jpg";
    else img.src = "blank.jpg";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="black.jpg" id="image1" onclick=diffImage(this) />​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/fnQ28/)